# How to print all values of Vector[]

Tags: java, printing, vector

I have a `Vector` of `Object[]` type that stores my data. How to print all it's objects ?

The code:

```
private static Vector<Object[]> vector = new Vector<Object[]>();


int event=0;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    vector.add( this.addToObject(System.currentTimeMillis(), event , "String") );
    event++;    
}

private Object[] addToObject(long t, int i,String s ){
    Object[] o = new Object[4];
    o[3] = s;
    o[2] = i;
    o[1] = "00000";
    o[0] = t;
    return o;
}
```

printing

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    main m = new Main();

    for(int i=0; i< m.vector.size(); i++){

    }
```

}

And I'd like to get sth like this :

1202393057117 1 OOOOO  String
1202393057117 2 OOOOO  String
1202393057118 3 OOOOO  String
1202393057118 4 OOOOO  String
1202393057118 5 OOOOO  String

Comment: Is this homework? If so please tag it as such.

Comment: Why are people still using Vector instead of ArrayList? Is there some underground network of books still using Vector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside your printing for loop:

```
Object[] objs = vector.get(i);
for (Object o : objs) {
    System.out.print(o + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 6):

Joshua Bloch, in [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), suggests using the for-each loop whenever possible:

```
for (Object[] array : vector) {
    for (Object obj : array) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

But since you are using the `Object[]` with fixed size of 4, with pre-known set of properties, it is highly advisable to create a new class:

```
class DataHolder {
    private someProperty;
    private someOtherProperty;
    ... + setters and getters
}
```

And instead of `array[2] = something`, you will have `dataHolder.setSomeProperty(something)` - far more readable and maintainable.

The next step is to override `toString()` (again as advised by Bloch) and implement it to print the whole internal state of the object.

And then the loop will look like this:

```
for (DataHolder dataHolder : vector) {
    System.out.println(dataHolder);
}
```

Comment: For beginners, the for each loop abstracts out important details that people learning the language should know.

Comment: they _should_ learn to use the for-each whenever that is possible. The regular for-loop is something trivial and I doubt anyone will have problems with it. Not using for-each, on the other hand, appears to be a problem often.

Comment: @jjnguy: abstraction is good. It is ignorance that is bad. And no, I don't believe using higher abstraction leads to ignorance.

Comment: +1, despite the fact that you butchered Bloch's first name. Joshua, not Joshia =)

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrays.deepToString(vector.get(i));
```

Or print them manually, as Lauri Lehtinen suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You can also print vector elements by using following code

```
Vector v = new Vector();
v.addElement("Java");
v.addElement("is");
v.addElement("programming");
v.addElement("language");

// enumerate the elements in the vector.
Enumeration vEnum = v.elements();
System.out.println("\nElements in vector:");
while(vEnum.hasMoreElements())
    System.out.print(vEnum.nextElement() + " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to do anything special. The code snippet below works just fine:

```
System.out.println("The vector is: " + vector);
```

Queries are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Within the loop:

```
Object[] o = m.vector.get(i);
System.out.printf("%d %d %s %s\n", o[0], o[2], o[1], o[3]);
```